# getDeclaredConstructor on an interface?

Tags: java, reflection

The javadoc for `Class::getDeclaredConstructor` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) says:

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified constructor
>   of the class **or interface** represented by this Class object.  [emphasis mine]

Since you can't declare a constructor for an interface, what could it mean to return a "specified constructor" of an interface?

I tried it on `Runnable.class` and got `NoSuchMethodException`.  Is there a case where `getDeclaredConstructor` will work on an interface?  Or is this language in the javadoc just an error?  Or does it mean something other than how I'm interpreting it?

Comment: If you've already accepted an answer why are you putting a bounty on the question?

Comment: @EJP I did not put the bounty there.  Also, the bounty was put there before I accepted the answer.  Maybe I shouldn't have accepted it--Pillar seems to think a more authoritative answer would be better, and that may make sense.

Comment: It's not an error actually.
Behaviour is in line with java doc:
**Throws:**
_NoSuchMethodException - if a matching method is not found._

As far as interface doesn't have constructor exception will be thrown.

Comment: @krems The _error_ is that they included the words _or interface_ in the javadoc.  If using this method on a `Class<interface>` always throws an exception, then there is no reason for those two words to be included.  The reason I asked the question was because I was wondering if there was some subtle case where it might be useful to pass a `Class<interface>`.  But apparently there isn't.

Comment: @ajb Accepted answer is your personal decision on what helped _you_ the best. (even if a more exhaustive answer exists)

Comment: @Insane thanks.  I'm a bit confused because I've never seen someone put a bounty on someone else's question before, and I have no idea how that works and what effect my accepting an answer has on that.

Comment: @ajb It has nothing to do with it, don't worry :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced by any of the answers. I still think it should be reworded in the documentation. I'm not questioning the existing behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A call to `Class.getConstructor` will result in a call to `Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors` to retrieve all declared constructors. The matching constructor is selected from that list:

```
private Constructor<T>[] privateGetDeclaredConstructors(boolean publicOnly) {
    ...
    // No cached value available; request value from VM
    if (isInterface()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Constructor<T>[] temporaryRes = (Constructor<T>[]) new Constructor<?>[0];
        res = temporaryRes;
    } else {
        res = getDeclaredConstructors0(publicOnly);
    }
    ...
    return res;
}
```

(I removed part of the code which deals with cached constructors).

So for interfaces the constructor list is always empty and a `NoSuchMethodException` will always be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

I don't consider this an error in javadoc. `Class` object can represent class or interface, there is no error in that statement.

If you're using reflection and explicitly ask for specific elements, you have to make sure that elements with the identification specified in the reflective calls exist. If you're asking for a **specific** constructor that does not exist in the provided `Class`, you'll get `NoSuchMethodException` be it a class for an interface, primitive type, array, void or simply a class that does not declare such a constructor.

Above I emphasised the word **specific**. For example, in a similar method that returns all constructors for a `Class` ([Class::getDeclaredConstructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--)) interfaces are handled appropriately:

> Returns an array of `Constructor` objects reflecting all the
>   constructors declared by the class represented by this `Class` object.
>   These are public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   constructors. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and
>   are not in any particular order. If the class has a default
>   constructor, it is included in the returned array. **This method returns
>   an array of length 0 if this `Class` object represents an
>   interface, a primitive type, an array class, or void.**

Answer (score -1):

This is the use case I can think of: on a reflection-based application, a method receives a Class argument. The method needs to construct an instance of the given class, so it checks for the declared constructors.
This is a simplified example that just prints the constructors on four different use cases:

1. A class instance invoking getClass()
2. An interface instance invoking getClass()
3. An actual ClassX.class
4. An actual InterfaceY.class

   ```
   public class Testctor {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new Testctor().testGetDeclCtors();
       }

       public void testGetDeclCtors() {
           Class1 c1 = new Class1(4);
           printClassInfo(c1.getClass());

           I2 i2 = c1;
           printClassInfo(i2.getClass());

           printClassInfo(Class1.class);

           printClassInfo(I2.class);
       }

       private void printClassInfo(Class<?> claz) {
           Constructor<?> ctor = null;
           try {
               ctor = claz.getDeclaredConstructor();
           } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
           }
           System.out.println(claz+": "+ctor);
       }
   }

   interface I2 {
   }

   class Class1 implements I2 {
       public Class1() {
       }

       public Class1(int x) {
       }
   }
   ```

This prints these results:

```
class test.Class1: public test.Class1()
class test.Class1: public test.Class1()
class test.Class1: public test.Class1()
interface test.I2: null
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to my question, because you're using `getDeclaredConstructors` with an `s` at the end.  That is a different method from the one I was asking about.